# Sharing/Invite CoreData iCloud documents with others

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

With with my coreData file syncing to iCloud, can I send a link to that file or an invite to a friend (who has a different iCloud account) so we can share that info through the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. iCloud does not allow direct file sharing links like Dropbox.
Also, you should not be directly syncing a CoreData sqlite file. CoreData has its own syncing mechanism for iCloud, and you should not sync it as a whole file. From Apple's documentation:

> You cannot simply move or copy an existing database file to iCloud.
>   Instead, you should use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's
>   migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: method to migrate
>   the database to the required location.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/index.html

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to be a feature of iCloud available in Reminders (from the Mac) and PhotoStream (from the app).  I'll keep digging around. I'll post anything I find.